# Horizontally flip a lot of pictures in GIMP

Tags: gimp, batch-processing

I have like a thousand pictures that I would like to flip them horizontally in GIMP, do you know how I can achieve that?

I guess I will have to use some kind of a batch process, but I'm really not familiar with it.

Comment: Sounds like you would be better of using GraphicsMagick.

Comment: Do you mean horizontal mirroring or rotating the image 180 degrees? What operating system? On a mac, you could maybe use [Automator](http://www.macosxautomation.com/services/learn/tut02/index.html). On a windows machine, probably [Irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com/).

Comment: For Unix/Linux/Mac, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92871/how-to-rotate-all-images-in-a-directory-with-imagemagick

Answer (score 5):

You can use ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick:

```
magick mogrify -flop *.png
gm mogrify -flop *.png
```

GraphicsMagick seems to be about 70% faster for this
operation on a directory full of out-of-the-camera JPEGs.

Use -flip to flip top-to-bottom instead of left-to-right.

Note that the images will be recompressed by "mogrify".
If you are working with JPEG images, you can use the "jpegtran" application (which is part of the libjpeg distribution) to rotate or flip images losslessly.  If you are working with PNG or GIF, this recompression is unavoidable.

Comment: I  wonder if they are on JPG format, the images are recompressed? or it is a recompression free process.

Answer (score 2):

For batch process there is the  [David's Batch Processor GIMP plugin](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/79281/batch-processing)

and the second is [BIMP. Batch Image Manipulation Plugin](http://registry.gimp.org/node/26259).

Good luck!