# Batch Processing

Tags: gimp, software-recommendation, batch-processing

I need to batch process 100's of images in one go, these are largely product photographs for my e-commerce store & the task are repetitive such as white background , image resizing,and compressing .

Currently , I use:

- GIMP - White Background ( Couldn't batch Process for white background)
- Faststone - for Batch Resizing

I find this laborious & time consuming ? Is there a better way ..Do recommend

Comment: are you on a Mac or PC?

Answer (score 3):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) can do batch image operations.

It's a command line program, so most of the work will be in reading the
manual and searching to find the right command to do what you need.

ImageMagick is actually a suite of a few different programs. The one for
performing bulk operations on many files is `mogrify`.

The example below removes transparency (resulting in a white background)
and resizes all .jpg files in the current location to 300 × 300
pixels.

```
mogrify -flatten -resize 300x300 *.jpg
```

You will need to read the
[mogrify](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php) documentation to
come up with the exact options you need to use for what you are trying to
do.

**Edit:** Since you mentioned using GIMP, I also wanted to point out that GIMP has a [batch processing mode](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/). I've personally never used this feature, but it may be useful if you have original files stored as .xcf files.

Comment: +1 for mentioning mogrify - the mere existence of this ImageMagick command is denied by almost everyone else :)

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher I vaguely remember a scenario a few years ago where I needed to do something that was supported by `convert` but not `mogrify`, so I ended up writing a bash script to do it instead. But you're right; mogrify isn't mentioned enough.

Answer (score 1):

Yo there!, I have used one plugin [David's Batch Processor GIMP plugin](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/79281/batch-processing)
its easy to use and stable, at least it can do the resizing part.

Other option is [BIMP. Batch Image Manipulation Plugin](http://registry.gimp.org/node/26259), it seems it manage a bit more options. But I haven tried yet.

But in the other hand, IMHO, as cited by Scribblemacher, the imagemagick way is better

Answer (score 0):

If you are using photoshop you may want to look into image proccessor within the script dropdown. Or better yet search Image Processor Pro (free photoshop script) and it will prove much more option and control.